# cant save mulitple records in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I cant save multiple records in cakephp3 v3.2. I have a field to reset to 0 on about 20 rows of data (see below). The below code doesnt save. I dont get an error and a debug of the data is correct but nothing happens, no errors. Just it doesnt reset that field to 0.

I can get it to work using execute method as below but why doesnt newentites work?

```
private function tmpschedules(  $tmpscheduleStudents=0, $tutorId=0){
      foreach ( $tmpscheduleStudents  as $key => $item) : 
       //  debug($item);
           $tmpscheduleStudents[$key]['allocated']=0;

      endforeach;   
   // exit;         
         $students_schedule = $this->Tmpschedules->newEntities($tmpscheduleStudents, ['validate' =>  false]);


     foreach (   $students_schedule as $key => $item) {
          debug($item);
             $result=$this->Tmpschedules->save($item, ['atomic' =>  false]);
      }     
      exit;    

    return   1;

}


//see allocated field is 0 before being saved but it doesnt save.

object(App\Model\Entity\Tmpschedule) {

    'student_id' => (int) 1039,
    'tutor_id' => (int) 92,
    'rank' => (int) 0,
    'inactive' => (int) 0,
    'weekday_start' => (int) 0,
    'start_order' => (int) 0,
    'allocated' => (int) 0,



 //this does work
      foreach ( $tmpscheduleStudents  as $key => $item) : 
           //  debug($item);
              // $tmpscheduleStudents[$key]['allocated']=0;
              $query = $this->Tmpschedules->query();
              $query->update()
                   ->set(['allocated' => 0])
                  ->where(['tutor_id' => $tutorId])
                 ->execute();

          endforeach;  



//result update which has allocated as o0 but doesnt save and no errors as you see below
    'student_id' => (int) 245,
        'tutor_id' => (int) 13,
        'rank' => (int) 0,
        'inactive' => (int) 0,
        'weekday_start' => (int) 0,
        'start_order' => (int) 0,
        'allocated' => (int) 0,
        '[new]' => true,
        '[accessible]' => [
            '*' => true
        ],
        '[dirty]' => [
            'student_id' => true,
            'tutor_id' => true,
            'rank' => true,
            'inactive' => true,
            'weekday_start' => true,
            'start_order' => true,
            'allocated' => true
        ],
        '[original]' => [],
        '[virtual]' => [],
        '[errors]' => [],
        '[invalid]' => [],
        '[repository]' => 'Tmpschedule2s'

    }
```

Comment: Why are you not trying "saveMany()", to save all data at once? @jagguy

Comment: my version is 3.2 so it wont work.

Comment: It is supported in version >= 3.2.8, so update your composer. @jagguy

Comment: havent updated before so not sure what to do yet but anyway why is the code not working for newentities?

Comment: Does `$item->errors()` have anything for you after the save call? What does `$result` look like?

Comment: I updated the OP with output and again nothing. I think I might give up on doing things with newentities and look at updating the software. Never liked this method

Comment: what if you set the ID in your foreach before you save? $this->Tmpschedules->id = $item->id

Comment: I have given up sorry on this as it is taking too much time , I will look to update cakephp3

Answer (score 0):

What is the field type? If the field type and the value you are inserting do not match it will be getting marshaled away. My guess is that is what is happening. The key difference is in one of your examples you are casting and in the other you are not casting also in some you use 0 vs false. Keep consistent.

The following should work

```
$students_schedule = $this->Tmpschedules->newEntities($tmpscheduleStudents, ['validate' =>  0]);
```

You could also get away with

```
$students_schedule = $this->Tmpschedules->newEntities($tmpscheduleStudents, ['validate' =>  (int)false]);
```

just make sure that your column type and value type match and that should resolve your issue. My example assumes you are using a numeric type field.